# Annoying warnings "Debug session was finished without being paused" in PhpStorm with Vagrant and Xdebug

Tags: php, vagrant, phpstorm, xdebug

I have properly running xdebug on vagrant on my local pc on Ubuntu. It shows its orange table with error info. My testing page is `localhost:8030`

In Chrome browser I have `Xdebug helper`.

The problem is that an annoying warning is displaying in PhpStorm each time I refresh the site:

> Debug session was finished without being paused
>   It may be caused by
>   path mappings misconfiguration or not synchronized local and remote
>   projects.
>   To figure out the problem check path mappings
>   configuration for 'localhost' server at PHP | Servers or enable Break at
>   first line in PHP scripts option (from Run menu).

I have checked path mappings configuration for 'localhost' server at "PHP | Servers" and they are OK. My PhpStorm project directory is associated to default Vagrant directory `/vagrant/web/`.

Enabling `Break at first line in PHP scripts option` does help but it is kind of an opportunism I think.

How to get rid of these PhpStorm warnings?

Comment: this may sound off the wall, but whenever i get a weirdo like that with any jetbrains IDE, i invalidate caches and restart.  Seems the best bug fixer amongst all their programmers.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg invalidate caches did not help.

Comment: So .. where does it break then? What file? What xdebug log has to say about that particular session? You need to provide details in order to be able to "fix" it. NOTE: you will also see this if you do not have any breakpoints setup but trying to debug. Or .. when you have breakpoints .. but they are on wrong lines or unreachable  places. Details please.

Comment: I get this all the time when I have multiple web apps running or doing ajax requests in the background.

Comment: @LazyOne After some workaround I got to conclusion that it is not unnormal that the warning is shown when there is no breakpoins in the file. When I put some the warning went out.

Comment: @trzczy You might need to add one more mapping to your public folder. This is where your `index.php` file lies. So usually there are two mappings. One for your project root directory and one for your public folder.

Answer (score 22):

For PhpStorm 2021.1.1 +

[Ctrl] + [Alt] + S
Settings : Php -> Debug

Scroll to Advanced settings and expand

Uncheck option Notify if debug session was finished without being paused

Comment: Thank you so so so much. I have fetch requests running in the bbackground. I don't care if these finish without being interrupted. These warnings were so annoying.

Comment: you sir... deserve a beer for this

Answer (score 12):

It would do this if there are no breakpoints being hit when debugging the script. The "break at first line" probably prevents PhpStorm from issuing you the warning, but otherwise it does exactly the same.

In case you *do* have breakpoints configured, and PhpStorm doesn't stop on them, then it is likely that you have path mappings configured wrongly.

Using Xdebug's `xdebug.remote_log=/tmp/xdebug.log` setting/feature to see which breakpoints PhpStorm tries to set, and see whether it does so for the correct paths. They will up as `breakpoint_set` commands in the log file.

Comment: Exactly what have happened with me. I placed a breakpoint inside a wp-cron job, which explains why it have not entered. Moment I placed a breakpoint on a linear function, it broke and have not displayed this message.